# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am getting this error when I'm try to run - npm run dev in my command prompt:

```
Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.
Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

Hash: af4cfdb00272137cb4d3
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 60ms
Built at: 02/05/2020 10:38:54 AM

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\dahiy\Desktop\Web developer Course\JS - Basics 2\forkit'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 dev: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is how my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry:'./src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    }, 
    mode:'development'  
};
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Sachin Dahiya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

I have tried everything to solve this error but not getting any solution to resolve this. Please help me out. Attaching the screenshot of the error here.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmoir.png)

Comment: are the following directories present: 'src' and 'src/js'?

Comment: @theBashShell: Yes. Here is the folder structure: Desktop-->Web developer Course-->JS - Basics 2-->forkit-->src-->js

Answer (score 0):

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
        filename:'bundle.js'
    }, 
    mode:'development'  
};
```

since you're on Windows, looks like the forward/backward slash confusion is the issue

Comment: I am still getting the same error after making the changes as mentioned above.

Comment: try deleting   "main": "index.js" from package.json

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the file for CAPS.
Running on the local machine was not giving error but when I was running on linux, it was giving me a similar error as above.

I found the issue with name of the file. While doing import I had

import Login from "./login";

But name of the file was Login.js
When I changed login to Login, it worked for me
import Login from "./Login";

Comment: That sounds like you had a typo, but that doesn't necessarily translate over to *this specific* problem. Checking for case typos is good general advice, but answers should be specific to the post

Comment: @Camille, the typo was not affecting the local run but was creating run issue during deployment.

Comment: That still doesn't make it related to the question